# Intellij - how to copy some text from tooltip messages to clipboard

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Is there a way in IntelliJ to copy some text from the tooltip warning message to the clipboard ?

Simple example (see attached printscreen) - I am trying to copy "-Xlintunchecked" text from the tooltip shown below, I am able to select a text using mouse, but when trying to copy using Ctrl-C or mouse right-click (in the hope that a context menu with copy option will be there), the tooltip dissapears.

Maybe it is somewhere something similar to "Problems view" in Eclipse, where I could see this warning message and copy it to the clipboard ?

In Eclipse it is very easy and intuitive, you can copy text fragments from warnings/messages directly from the editor.

[image]

Comment: All tooltip text can be copied on Alt+Click. When copying partial text indeed the tooltip disappears on Ctrl+C. But I still can copy partial text from tooltip.You can vote related issue: [IDEA-168283](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168283)